# javafx HTMLEditor (Webkit.WebPage): custom font size

Tags: javafx, fonts, size, html, html-editor

I've a problem with the javafx html editor. I customised the shown elements and now i need to change the font family & size drop down list.

I got it working, that I can insert my custom font sizes, BUT then nothing happens after choosing between sizes. So I think there is probably any change listener working not with my inserted values?

---

Status Update 11.08.16:

The actual case is, that I added the HTMLEditor, HTMLEditorBehavior and HTMLEditorSkin java files to my project. I recognized then, that the editor 
is reading in 7 fixed sizes from a property file and updates the webkit.WebPage with those values if the dropdown changes its value.

The problem: This values are html values from 1 to 7. The generated html tag is  which only takes values from 1 to 7. For my application I need to have values like 16pt -> so i'm looking for any way to access the part where the html tag is added and instead of  I want to use  tags.

Any ideas ? If it helps you, I can upload a short test-project, where I added the htmleditor files for debugging - just let me know pls.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the relevant code snippet you've tried so far.

Comment: following what @UnixOne said it will also make it easier for you as some1 will just copy your code edit it and send it back you, and all you do is run.

Comment: any ideas to the status update problem ?